# Trigger click on page load to open accordion item from external link based on hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

Thanks for reading this.

I'm trying to use these lines to load a page with an accordion menu item open (from an external link according to a hash), but it's not working.

I'm using:

```
    if(location.hash) {
       $('a[href="#' + $(this) + '"]').trigger('click');
       });
```

or

```
if(location.hash) {
   $(".accordion[href$="+location.hash+"]").trigger('click');
   });
```

It's also combined with 2 more scripts: 1 for the accordion and 1 for the scroll down to the hash. Complete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/camilamss/jLjbcLpw/7/

External link I'm using: `<a href="Untitled.html#agriculture">Link</a>`

Thanks again, all the best!

Comment: Try `$(".accordion[href$='"+location.hash+"']")` (with single-quotes wrapping the `href` value)